# How to make junit for jaxws service with axis2

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm developing jaxws annotated webservice and I'm deploying it to axis2 (1.5.1) running at tomcat (6.0.20) in a folder named 'servicejars'. So far so good. But it is undeployable to the SimpleAxis2Server to make junit tests. 
Deploying as service archive (.aar) doesn't run for jaxws webservice as discussed here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4611.

How to make junit for jaxws service with axis2? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your description contains two problems.

First problem is that bug. If your web services cannot be deployed at all and no client can call them, you have to find a workaround! I cannot help with that part.

The second problem is finding the right junit test strategy. My advice is the following: if you can avoid it, don't call real web services with junit tests on the client side. Find a way to call your annotated methods from junit tests sitting on the server side. Your unit tests will be more efficient and won't depend on a jaxws client.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.
I use the onboard solution of java6 (Endpoint.publish(..)) to publish the webservice from within junit.
It is very easy.